# Using Java EE BeanManager, is it possible to get reference of Instance<AnyClass>?

Tags: java, java-ee-6

I'm trying to programatically lookup CDI proxies using javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager.

I'm able to resolve all beans except Instance.

This is the code..

```
public interface Service {
       public void doSomething();
    }

    public class Serviceimpl implements Service{
        public void doSomething(){
          system.out.println("Impl clazz");
        }
    }

    public class LoginAction{
      @Inject Service svc;

      public void logintest(){
        svc.doSomething();
      }

    }
```

The same functionality works fine as expected when I do this

```
 public class LoginAction{
      public void logintest(){
        Service svc = BeanManager.getReference(Service.class);
        svc.doSomething();
      }

    }
```

Although when there is more than one implementation, I'm doing this

```
  public class LoginAction{
          @Inject Instance<Service> services;
                  public void logintest(){
            for(Service s : services){
                s.doSomething();
            }
          }

        }
```

And this works perfectly fine. But I'm trying to do the same via BeanManager but it won't work.

```
 public void logintest(){
       Instance<Service> svc = BeanManager.getReference(Instance<Service>..); // not sure how to program here. This is where help is needed
        for(Service s : services){
            s.doSomething();
        }
      }
```

The  main reason of trying to programatically/canonically lookup is this pience of logic may be in a static block..